# Why are parentheses needed in Kivy but not in Python?

Tags: python, popup, kivy

If I want to add an `on_press` event to a popup in any program, I can do it directly in python or using kv language.

If I use Python, for example

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class SomePopup(Popup):
    pass

class SomeBox(Box):
    popup = SomePopup()
    popup.title = 'anything'
    popup.content = Button(text='anytext', on_press=popup.dismiss)
```

And in KV language, supposing I make the same popup, it will be.

```
<SomePopup>
    title: 'anything'
    content: popupContent
    Button:
        id: popupContent
        text: 'anytext'
        on_press: root.dismiss()
```

So, in python, i have to use `on_press=popup.dismiss` and in kv language `on_press: root_dismiss()`

I don't understand why in kivy language I should use parentheses and not in python. Could you help me please?

Comment: Because that's how the designers of the two languages designed them.

Comment: For the same reason you have to use `:` instead of `=`; they are *different languages*, with *different syntax*. You might as well ask *"why do I have to use different words in French and English?"*

Comment: @jonrsharpe That doesn't quite work. The part after `on_press:` is a fragment of Python code, or at least appears to be. To keep with the language analogy: Why does the spelling of French loan words differ from the source word?

Comment: First of all, this is a question for programmers.stackexchange.com . Also, the short answer is that python references a callable object by giving the name without the call operator `()`, which would return the result of calling the object. Apparently, Kivy distinguishes the two based on context.

Comment: Some of these comments point out the language difference, but it's important that 'Kivy' isn't doing anything special here - these two things are both pure python, it's just that one involves passing the method (`popup.dismiss`) to be called later, while the other involves directly running a line of python code (`root.dismiss()`). Although the latter is in kivy language, it makes no difference here, it would be the same if you wrote it all in the python file such as in the `on_press` method.

Answer (score 7):

Although both achieve the same things, kv and Python do them in different ways.

In Python, when you do `Button(text='anytext', on_press=popup.dismiss)`, you're essentially telling kivy: when a press occurs, call the `popup.dismiss` method. That is, you're passing it an object (a class method in this case) which kivy will call at the correct time.

In kv, when you do `on_press: root.dismiss()`, when a press event occurs, kivy will execute whatever text is after the colon (`root.dismiss()` in this case). So you need to do the call to the `root.dismiss()` yourself in that text.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate: when you put callback code in kv, it's like making a lambda.

So this kv code:

```
on_press: popup.dismiss()
```

is equivalent to the following Python code:

```
Button(text='anytext', on_press=lambda *args: popup.dismiss())
```

The only reason `on_press=popup.dismiss` works is because `Popup.dismiss()` swallows extra arguments (the `Button` instance is passed as the first argument). So in this case it seems that the two are equivalent, but they usually are not.

Take this code, for example:

```
def callback():
    pass

button = Button(on_press=callback)
```

When the `Button` is pressed, it calls `callback(self)` - which will raise an exception as `callback` takes no arguments.

By comparison, this code works like `dismiss` does:

```
def callback(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

button = Button(on_press=callback)
```

And, of course, in kv:

```
on_press: callback()
```

...which works regardless of which `callback` definition you used.